# Teradata Multiload Script stuck at LOGON

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I made this mload script and it gets stuck at LOGON. I have access to the db and similar logons work fine in fastload scripts.

Here is the script:

```
.LOGTABLE UD821.FRC_RPT_PERD_Log;
.LOGON oneview/uid,pw;



.BEGIN IMPORT MLOAD TABLES UD821.FRC_RPT_PERD SESSIONS 5;




.LAYOUT InputFile_layout;

       .field PERD_END_RPT_DT   (VARCHAR(20));
       .field RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD  (VARCHAR(20));
       .field PERD_NM        (VARCHAR(30));
       .field QTR_NUM           (VARCHAR(2));
       .field YEAR_NUM          (VARCHAR(4));
       .field RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM  (VARCHAR(10));
       .field DATA_VLDTN_IND    (VARCHAR(1));
       .fieldEDW_PUBLN_ID      (VARCHAR(18));

.DML LABEL FRC_RPT_PERD_INSERT;


.INSERT INTO UD821.FRC_RPT_PERD ( PERD_END_RPT_DT, RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD, PERD_NM, QTR_NUM, YEAR_NUM, RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM,
                          DATA_VLDTN_IND, EDW_PUBLN_ID )
    VALUES ( 

CASE WHEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,3,1) = '/'
AND Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,6,1) = '/'
THEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,7,4)||'-'||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,1,2)||'-' ||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,4,2)

WHEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,2,1) = '/'
AND Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,5,1) = '/'
THEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,6,4)||'-0'||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,1,1)||'-' ||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,3,2)

WHEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,2,1) = '/'
AND Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,4,1) = '/'
THEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,5,4)||'-0'||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,1,1)||'-0' ||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,3,1)

WHEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,3,1) = '/'
AND Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,5,1) = '/'

THEN Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,6,4)||'-'||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,1,2)||'-0' ||Substr(PERD_END_RPT_DT,4,1)
ELSE PERD_END_RPT_DT
END (Date,Format 'yyyy-mm-dd'),, :RPT_PERD_TYPE_CD, :PERD_NM, :QTR_NUM, :YEAR_NUM, :RPT_PERD_TYPE_NM,
                          :DATA_VLDTN_IND, :EDW_PUBLN_ID ) ;

.import infile C:\Documents and Settings\bkp343\Desktop\FRC_RPT_PERD.csv
 format vartext  ','
 display errors
 nostop
 layout InputFile_Layout
 apply FRC_RPT_PERD_INSERT;

.end mload;
 .logoff;
```

Is there something obviously wrong here? It just hangs at 0002 LOGON.

Comment: To clarify, 'by similar logons', did you mean the same logon which are using for MLOAD. If it still doesn't work, then try hard-coding the user name and password and check.

Comment: When I use the exact same database, uid, and pw to LOGON in a fastload script it works fine.

Comment: Hmm..never seen this issue before. Are you sure MLOAD is installed on the system?

Comment: Just a thought...if you are on a production system, then there may not be enough loader slots available..

Comment: wouldnt it give me an error in that case? and mload is def installed. I just realized I don't have permission to SELECT or INSERT on that log table, think that could be the issue?

Comment: It will login and then give an error if it's an access problem. I think either the loader slots are full, or if you running through some scheduler (like Tivoli or Control-M), it's having a loading slot limit which is currently completely used up.

Comment: What release of Teradata are you running? Have you asked your DBA's about the workload rules in place at the time you are submitting the load? Do you have access to Viewpoint to monitor your own sessions?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem so I landed here. In my case the solution was trivial: instead of running my mload script: '**mload -b < script.mload**' (correct) I tried 'mload -b script.mload' (incorrect).
The first is correct

Answer (score 0):

We just experienced this exact problem while trying to run the script remotely over a DSL line.  The fix was to use the IP address rather than the alias.  Apparently there is something that hangs in the LDAP authentication at slower DSL speeds. The same script worked on a faster remote connection.